# Improve code that periodically query SQLite database

Tags: php, sqlite

I have an sqlite database that I query from PHP periodically. The query is always the same and it returns me a string. Once the string changes in the database the loop ends.

The following code is working, but I am pretty sure this is not the optimal way to do this...

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('db.sqlite');
    }
}

$loop = True;
while ($loop == True) {
    sleep(10);
    $db = new MyDB();
    if (!$db) {
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
        echo "Opened database successfully\n";
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT status from t_jobs WHERE name=' . $file_name;

    $ret = $db->query($sql);
    $state = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    $output = (string)$state['status'];
    if (strcmp($output, 'FINISHED') == 0) {
        $loop = False;
    }
    echo $output;
    $db->close();
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you try to achieve, could you explain this ?

Comment: Initially (code not shown) I trigger a job (to a cluster). Job information is stored in the database. Once the job is finished it writes the status to the database. With the above code I check the change in the database. The thing is that the job might take some time to finish (1 minute - 15 minutes)

Comment: ok, so you only use php to know if the job is done in a **console**, right ?

Comment: or is this script running on a webserver ?

Comment: Yes. Then I will take the output of the job and render it to the screen.

Comment: "yes" what, web server or cli ?

Comment: sorry, webserver I meant

Comment: You could create an interval with javascript that makes an ajax-call every x-seconds. the receiving script peeks in the database and returns true or false. If true, stop the interval. If false continue as long as you want (as long as the client browser is open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get an output immediately and a kind of interface, I think The best solution for your problem might be to use HTTP long polling. This way, it will not hold the connection for hours if the job is not done:

- you will need to code a javascript snippet (in another html or php page) that runs an ajax call to your current php code.
- Your web server (and so, your php code) will keep the connection opened for a while until the job is done **or a time limit is reached** (say 20-30 seconds)
- if the job is not done, the javascript will make another ajax call and everything will start again, keeping the connection, etc... until you get the expected output status...

**BEWARE :** this solution will not work on any hosting provider

You will need to set the `max_execution_time` to a higher value than the default one see [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) for this.

I think you can find many things on http long polling with php/javascript on google / stack overflow...